# Difference between -ㄹ/을 것입니다 and -ㄹ/을 거예요

Tags: grammar

I have came across this sentence from a [lesson](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit1/unit-1-lessons-1-8/unit-1-lesson-1/):

> 저의 어머니는 올해 한국에 올 것입니다 = My mom will come to Korea this year

I am confused about the using of 것 here. What is the difference between that sentence and the one below?

> 저의 어머니는 올해 한국에 올 거예요.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have the same meaning with the same basic structure for future tense:

> V + -ㄹ/을 + 것 + 이다

However, they differ in two ways:

1. [Formal (하십시오체)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_speech_levels#Hasipsio-che) vs [Polite (해요체)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_speech_levels#Haeyo-che) style
2. The second one uses the common contracted form of 것 (거)

Note that the styles and contractions could have been swapped around to also produce the variations as -올 겁니다 and -을 것이에요.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. However, -입니다. is mostly used in the formal environment or normally, in the books.

거예요 is from 것이에요. It is its shortened form. This form is normally used in speaking. (All '-요' form.)

The meaning of '-것' indicates what he will do. '-ㄹ 것입니다', '-ㄹ 거예요', '-ㄹ 것이에요', etc is a set of 'will' and 'verb'

There are so many endings for the verbs. So, if they look similar, you can consider that they have the same meaning. But they may have a slightly different feeling - formal, cute, funny, surprise, childish, etc.

We will help you out if you want faster answer: https://discord.gg/j9Knkyc